# How do I configure the ZDM proxy for TLS?

Tags: cassandra, database-migration, datastax-zdm-proxy

I am using the open source Zero Down Time (ZDM) migration tool
https://github.com/datastax/zdm-proxy.git to split the current Cassandra cluster into multiple clusters.

The first question is

**Does the tool support TLS since there is no instructions for TLS setup in the documents?**

**Note: I am not using the automation version of ZDM proxy.**

I was able to make the ZDM proxy working without TLS but blocked on trying to enable TLS,

**Here is their setup.**

```
export ORIGIN_TLS_USER_DIR_PATH=xxx
export ORIGIN_TLS_SERVER_CA_FILENAME=yyy
export ZDM_PROXY_TLS_USER_DIR_PATH=zzz
export ZDM_PROXY_TLS_CA_FILENAME=wwww
```

Below are part of the proxy log

```
INFO[0000] Starting ZDM proxy version 2.1.0
INFO[0000] Proxy TLS was not configured.
INFO[0000] TLS was not configured for Origin
```

which shows the TLS on the origin and proxy are not set up.

Are the configurations set up correctly? If not, what are the correct configurations to enable the proxy to the origin cluster one way TLS?

I expect the supporters from the ZDM tool to let me know whether the non-automated tool support TLS. If it does, what configurations needed to make TLS work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note: the names of the env vars are always prefixed with `ZDM_`. The automation typically asks for the path of the directory where the files are, and then for the name (without path) of each file, which is what you will see in the doc explanations. However, **in the env vars, you have to set the path and file name for each file**.

For application-to-proxy one-way TLS they need all the following variables (see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/migrate/tls.html#_application_to_proxy_tls)):

- `ZDM_ORIGIN_TLS_SERVER_CA_PATH` - path and name of the Server CA
- `ZDM_ORIGIN_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH` - path and name of the Server
  certificate
- `ZDM_ORIGIN_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH`  - path and name of the
  Server key

For proxy-to-cluster one-way TLS they only need the Server CA of the cluster (see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/migrate/tls.html#_proxy_to_self_managed_cluster_tls)):

- `ZDM_ORIGIN_TLS_SERVER_CA_PATH` - path and name of Origin's Server CA
- `ZDM_TARGET_TLS_SERVER_CA_PATH` - path and name of Target's Server CA

Note that all the files must be in non-binary, PEM format.